# Getting "Error Occurred" (only) when implementing my Facebook Login. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, yetanotherforum, yaf

I'm trying to implement a Facebook Login on the forum in my website.  The code is perfectly correct -- It's been tested and I've quadrupled-checked that.

**The button is there**! When clicking the "Log in with Facebook" button ... it brings up the pop-up box where you enter your FB info, but when you click "Authorize App", it doesn't redirect me and register the user.  I get a tiny popup box that simply says "Error Occurred" and nothing else.  Here's the error:

[image: Login Error]

But I think I'm doing something wrong on my actual **Facebook app page**. Here's what I have:

[image: My App Settings:]

[image: My App Details:]

The only thing I can think of is that I should put something in the **namespace** (but have no idea what to put), or that the **App Domains** is incorrect ... since the Login button is at www.domain.com/knowledgebase/default.aspx?g=login ... but when I tried to enter that into the App Domain, the FB App page said the domain was invalid.  The only thing it accepts is www.domain.com.  Anybody familiar with Facebook apps, or anybody who could offer guidance -- it'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> but when you click "Authorize App", it doesn't redirect me and register the user. I get a tiny popup box that simply says "Error Occurred" and nothing else.

That seems to be a simple JavaScript `alert` message – and I doubt it’s coming from Facebook, it’s more likely to come from your script that you run while processing the login response.

> or that the App Domains is incorrect ... since the Login button is at www.domain.com/knowledgebase/default.aspx?g=login ... but when I tried to enter that into the App Domain, the FB App page said the domain was invalid. The only thing it accepts is www.domain.com.

Congratulations – now you know the difference between a *URL* and a *domain*.

Comment: lol .... thanks CBroe, yes, I understand the difference between a domain an a URL.  It may have something to do with FB's all.js (connect.facebook.com/en_US/all.js) but I'm not sure ... still working on it.

Comment: But I've shared source code from others with the same login, and they got theirs to work, so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the Facebook SDK, and how I configured (or misconfigured) it ...